# How to search for value in one table if not searcha another?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables where similar records stored. I have to search for existing record, where reference value matches one record if record is not found in first table, I need to search second table.

I tried querying like this but it returns all the records

```
SELECT * FROM keys WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM store_1 WHERE store_1.key_number LIKE '%1726-1726280-17998%') or EXISTS(SELECT * FROM store_2 WHERE store_2.key_number LIKE '%1726-1726280-17998%');
```

Comment: Use a `UNION` for this.

Comment: Why use LIKE here? Can't this just be replaced by = ?

Comment: @JonasMetzler In actual query I replaced it with $1

Answer (score 1):

As I understood with union I can return records with same number of columns

```
SELECT * FROM store_1 WHERE store_1.key_number LIKE '%1726-1726280-17998%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM store_1 WHERE store_2.key_number LIKE '%1727-1727265-11276%';
```

Comment: Think about using UNION ALL rather than UNION (unless pure duplicates from both queries are really possible and need to be filtered out). This will likely be faster. You should furthermore avoid using * and write a proper column selection instead. Otherwise, you are on risk of getting errors as soon as one of the tables will be altered.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * FROM store_1
WHERE 
    store_1.key_number LIKE '%1726-1726280-17998%' 
    OR store_2.key_number LIKE '%1727%'
```

You can try this version if you'd not want a UNION of the tables, it combines both conditions into a single SELECT statement like you intended initially.